# Tensorflow: Implemented Hourglass model for human pose estimation but it's not converging

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to tensorflow. I have to make human pose estimator. I implemented [stacked hourglass model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06937.pdf) but it's not converging.

here's my code. I am not expert in tensorflow so I thought maybe my code have fault or I didn't understand the paper properly.

x_image is the input image (-1,256,256,3) and y_true is the set of heat map (-1,128,128,12). Each heatmap have one peak which specifies the position of joint.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
tf.reset_default_graph()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

def init_weights(shape):
    init_random_dist = tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev = 0.1)
    return tf.Variable(init_random_dist)

def init_bias(shape):
    init_bias_vals = tf.constant(0.1, shape = shape)
    return tf.Variable(init_bias_vals)
    
def conv2d(x,W):
    # x --> [batch, H, W, Channels]
    # W --> [filter H, filter W, Channels In, Channels Out]
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')

def max_pool_2by2(x):
    # x --> [batch,h,w,c]
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'VALID')

def convolutional_layer(input_x, shape):
    W = init_weights(shape)
    b = init_bias([shape[3]])
    return tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv2d(input_x, W) ,b))

def residual_layer(convo):
  convo_1 = convolutional_layer(convo, [1,1,256,128])
  convo_2 = convolutional_layer(convo_1, [3,3,128,128])
  convo_3 = convolutional_layer(convo_2, [1,1,128,256])
  return convo_3

def hourglass(convo, size):

  if size == 4.0:
    convo = residual_layer(convo)
    convo = residual_layer(convo)
    convo = residual_layer(convo)
    return convo
  
  convo = residual_layer(convo)
  convo_1 = tf.nn.max_pool(convo, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'VALID')

  convo = hourglass(convo_1, size/2.0)

  convo_1 = residual_layer(convo_1)
  convo = tf.add(convo, convo_1)
  convo = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(convo, (int(size),int(size)))

  return convo


x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None, 256, 256 , 3])
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 128, 128, 12])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 256, 256, 3])

# input

convo = convolutional_layer(x_image, shape = [7,7,3,256])
convo = hourglass(convo, 256.0)
convo = convolutional_layer(convo, shape = [3,3,256,12])
y_pred = tf.nn.max_pool(convo, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding = 'VALID')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Itg is a bit difficult to say without knowing the full context and data. It seems you have just one image? That is most likely not enough for training.

Maybe you can also draw the model that you want to achieve in tensorflow?

You could try to change the learning rate to some other value (e.g. larger) to make it converge. Possibly you need to implement a scheduler for the learning rate to dynamically adapt it depending on the situation (see for an example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer?hl=en).